# Excel VBA - Two IE popups with same title

Tags: excel, vba, internet-explorer, vbscript

I am writing a VBA automation of IE. App is looking for particular ticket number and attempts to assign it to a user. Once button on the webpage is clicked, it might, under some conditions, return up to two alerts, both with same window title ("Message from webpage"), that require pressing OK button.

I am able to catch first pop up, but am unable to handle second one. I think the best way to deal with the issue would be reading message from these popups, but I have no idea, how to do this. It appears that both wscripts are catching first popup, and are unable to detect second one. Would you be able to help, please?

I have tried with the below, but no luck:

```
            '' If ticket was found and is not assigned to any user, run script to handle popup
            If sBut(currentPos + 11).innerHTML <> currentUser Then
                pid = Shell("wscript.exe ""pathToScript\msgClick.vbs""")
            End If

                pid2 = Shell("wscript.exe ""pathToScript\itemClaimed.vbs""")
                zBut = sBut(currentPos + 13).getElementsByTagName("input")
                zBut.Click
```

Once zBut is clicked and both popus show up, script handles only first one, leaving second untouched.

Below is code for msgClick.vbs (and itemClaimed.vbs, both are the same - I thought that running two separate files could help)

```
Set wshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

Do
    windowLookUp = wshShell.AppActivate("Message from webpage")
    
Loop Until windowLookUp = True
    WScript.sleep 500
    windowLookUp = wshShell.AppActivate("Message from webpage")
    If windowLookUp = True then
        windowLookUp = wshShell.AppActivate("Message from webpage")
        WScript.Sleep 10
        wshShell.SendKeys "{enter}"
    end if
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Silly me.
Instead of running two scripts from VBA, one can be launched from VBA, and other one just after first one is executed. Works like a charm.

```
Set wshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

Do
    windowLookUp = wshShell.AppActivate("Message from webpage")
    
Loop Until windowLookUp = True
    WScript.sleep 500
    windowLookUp = wshShell.AppActivate("Message from webpage")
    If windowLookUp = True then
        windowLookUp = wshShell.AppActivate("Message from webpage")
        WScript.Sleep 10
        wshShell.SendKeys "{enter}"
        
        dim objShell
        Set objShell = Wscript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
        objShell.Run "pthToScript\itemClaimed.vbs"
        
        Set objShell = Nothing
    end if
```